# puppeteer page.evaluate page not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I want to type inside an input with puppeteer, but it returns me an error: page is not defined

```
async function login(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "networkidle2"});
    await page.evaluate(async() =>{
        await page.type('#i0116','prova', {delay:200})
        document.getElementById('idSIButton9').click();
    })
}
```

I cant use 'document.getElementById('i0116').value = 'prova';'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use page or page.type inside page.evaluate.

So the correct way to do is this,

```js
await page.type('#i0116','prova', {delay:200})
await page.evaluate(async() =>{
  document.getElementById('idSIButton9').click();
})
```

or using the native page.click api from puppeteer,

```js
await page.type('#i0116','prova', {delay:200})
await page.click('#idSIButton9')
```

Comment: can't type in `input type='date'`

Comment: No need for the `evaluate` callback to be `async`. That can be clearer as `page.$eval("#idSIButton9", el => el.click())`.